# How to ImportJSON, specifically NBA stats, into Google Sheets

Tags: json, google-sheets

I am struggling with importing data from a URL I will list below.  I have tried all import options and have also taken an ImportJSON function from https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON/blob/master/ImportJSON.gs.

The site I want to import is: https://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashplayerstats?College=&Conference=&Country=&DateFrom=&DateTo=&Division=&DraftPick=&DraftYear=&GameScope=&GameSegment=&Height=&LastNGames=10&LeagueID=00&Location=&MeasureType=Base&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=PerGame&Period=0&PlayerExperience=&PlayerPosition=&PlusMinus=N&Rank=N&Season=2018-19&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&ShotClockRange=&StarterBench=&TeamID=0&TwoWay=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=&Weight=

Let me know what I'm missing, I think my issue is that I can't seem to figure out the correct query to import, but I'm really unsure.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

If I am going about this in the wrong direction, any guidance to right my ship would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**you can try to use this custom fx:**

```
=IMPORTJSON("url-here", "xpath-here")
```

---

```
function IMPORTJSON(url,xpath){

  try{
    // /rates/EUR
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var content = res.getContentText();
    var json = JSON.parse(content);

    var patharray = xpath.split("/");
    //Logger.log(patharray);

    for(var i=0;i<patharray.length;i++){
      json = json[patharray[i]];
    }

    //Logger.log(typeof(json));

    if(typeof(json) === "undefined"){
      return "Node Not Available";
    } else if(typeof(json) === "object"){
      var tempArr = [];

      for(var obj in json){
        tempArr.push([obj,json[obj]]);
      }
      return tempArr;
    } else if(typeof(json) !== "object") {
      return json;
    }
  }
  catch(err){
      return "Error getting data";  
  }

}
```

- **https://youtu.be/EXKhVQU37WM**
- **https://youtu.be/k0su6345KDI**